# ASP.NET Web API: Post Method from default ValuesController is not working in RC version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

When creating a default ASP.NET Web Api project, default ValuesController has post method like this:

```
// POST api/values
public void Post(string value)
{
}
```

I was trying to test this POST method from Filder with HTTP request:

```
POST /api/values

User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

value=abc
```

That was surprised to me, the input parameter **value** is **null**, not **abc**. It surely worked in beta version, but in RC version, Am I doing something wrong OR it is not working like this anymore?

Of course we have another way to work around by creating strong type object below:

```
public Class TestDto
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public void Post(TestDto testDto)
{  
}
```

Or use Json.

But I would like to have more understanding on this.

Comment: are you sure that you have public void Post in your controller? or is it public ActionResult Post(string something)

Comment: Yes, I am sure, Actioneuslt is in MVC, not Web API

Comment: Oh I see, I seem to have mixed up MVC and Web API. Thanks Cuong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) By default, simple types are taken from the URI. To read a simple type from the request body, add the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter. (Known issue with the project template. In the RTM release, the project template will include this in ValuesController.)

(2) For formurl-encoded, send a simple type as "=abc" not "value=abc"; see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1#sending_simple_types.